# Is there a matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$, with $A$ being diagonalizable?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have the following matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -7 & 1 \\
    0 & 4 & 0 \\
    -2 & 1 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
I already found the eigenvalues which are $$\lambda_1=1$$  $$\lambda_2=2$$ $$\lambda_3=4$$ They are distinct so the matrix is clearly diagonalizable. I know a matrix is similar to its diagonal matrix so we can write this as follows: $$A= PDP^{-1}$$
We also have that : $$A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$$ 
Now is it possible to find $B$ such that $B^2=A$ ? I have been trying to use the fact that $A$ is similiar to its diagonal, but i do not know if i have to use that or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guide:

Try to compute $(PD^\frac12P^{-1})^2$

Comment: Ohhh nice i can see it now :D. Does it work for a matrix with real coefficients too?

Comment: I thought your current matrix has real coefficients?

Comment: Yes it has, sorry that was a silly question! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I see, it need not be the case, for example, let $A=-1$, unless you want to work with complex number, it doesn't exist for $n=2$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh It's not possible if you want $B$ to be diagonalizable, but how about $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)^2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$?

Comment: sure, I was referring to the scalar $-1$ having no real square root.